# PySpark Error: cannot resolve '`timestamp`'

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, debugging, pyspark

I have to find the exact hour that most checkins occur in the Yelp dataset but I'm running up against this error for some reason. Here is my code so far:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

square_udf_int = udf(lambda z: square(z), IntegerType())

checkin = spark.read.json('yelp_academic_dataset_checkin.json.gz')
datesplit = udf(lambda x: x.split(','),ArrayType(StringType()))
checkin.select('business_id',datesplit('date').alias('dates')).withColumn('checkin_date',explode('dates'))
datesplit = udf(lambda x: x.split(','),ArrayType(StringType()))
dates = checkin.select('business_id',datesplit('date').alias('dates')).withColumn('checkin_date',explode('dates'))
dates = dates.select("checkin_date")
dates.withColumn("checkin_date", F.date_trunc('checkin_date',
                   F.to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"))).show(truncate=0)
```

And the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1112.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`timestamp`' given input columns: [checkin_date];;
'Project [date_trunc(checkin_date, to_timestamp('timestamp, Some(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC')), Some(Etc/UTC)) AS checkin_date#190]
+- Project [checkin_date#176]
   +- Project [business_id#6, dates#172, checkin_date#176]
      +- Generate explode(dates#172), false, [checkin_date#176]
         +- Project [business_id#6, <lambda>(date#7) AS dates#172]
            +- Relation[business_id#6,date#7] json
```

dates is just a Spark dataframe with one column named: "checkin_date" with only datetimes, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you obtain simply means that in the following line of code, you are trying to access a column named `timestamp` and that it does not exist.

```py
dates.withColumn("checkin_date", F.date_trunc('checkin_date',
                   F.to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'")))
```

Indeed, here is the signature of the `to_timestamp` function:

```py
pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp(col, format=None)
```

The first argument is the column, the second is the format. I am assuming you are trying to parse a date and then truncate it. Let's say you want to truncate the date to the month level. The correct way to do it would be:

```py
dates.withColumn("checkin_date", F.date_trunc('month',
                   F.to_timestamp('checkin_date', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'")))
```

Comment: Hi, Oli. Thank you! When I try to run this to truncate the date to just the hour level, and look at a couple of the rows, I'm getting all nulls for each row.

Comment: That means that the date format is incorrect. Check that it matches the way your dates are formatted. You may add an example in your question if you need help. Your format should work with dates like this: "2021-11-04 17:00:34 UTC". If your strings do not contain UTC, simply remove it from the format.

Comment: Oh! That worked. I just had to remove UTC. Do you know how I might then select the top most frequent hour from the new dataframe?

Comment: I figured it out. Using: row1 = df1.agg({"x": "max"}).collect()[0]

Comment: Nice ;) Glad I could help!